# How can I run multiple instances of bitlbee on OS X?

Tags: macos, irssi

I've been using bitlbee on OS X for a while now, but I've hit a roadblock when trying to use it the way I'd like to.

I have a .plist file created which launches bitlbee at boot, and thats working fine. I then use irssi to connect, and use my work jabber, as well as GTalk and Facebook chat.

Ideally, I'd like to use 2 instances of bitlbee, with 2 instances of irssi – thus keeping my personal comms seperate from business related ones.

I can't quite figure out (via `launchctl` and `.plist` files) how to get two instances of bitlbee running at boot, listening on different ports (6667 and 6668 for simplicity). Once that is working, it's a simple matter of having irssi connect to `localhost:port` and all is well.

Thoughts or ideas? Configs can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a single instance of Bitlbee.  Just use a different login from the second irssi.

If you actually want a second instance of Bitlbee, make a second config file and have it listen on a different port.  Then run the second Bitlbee using the second config file (use the "-c /path/to/second.conf" in the startup script).  Then use the second instance of irssi to connect to the second Bitlbee.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/bitlbee and http://en.linuxreviews.org/Bitlbee should help with the needed syntax.